# Content: Open-quote is showing as a single quote

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Content: Open-quote and the first time I use it, it looks fine, but the second time its a single quote and that isn't what I want.  Here is a jsfiddle showing the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/rx3nu2hv/

HTML

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class='testimonial'>
            <blockquote><p>John doe provides an excellent service in a record time.  We needed him to design a mobile compatible website and he was able to complete the job earleir than we had anticipated and with higher quality than you would expect from most.</p></blockquote>
                <div class='testimonial-left'>
                    <p>Jane Doe</p>
                    <p>Software Developer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class='testimonial'>
            <blockquote><p>John Doe provides an excellent service in a record time.  We needed him to design a mobile compatible website and he was able to complete the job earleir than we had anticipated and with higher quality than you would expect from most.</p></blockquote>
                <div class='testimonial-left'>
                    <p>Jane Doe</p>
                    <p>Software Developer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/row-fluid-->
```

CSS

```
.testimonial blockquote
{

  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";

}

.testimonial blockquote:before {
  color: #ccc;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}

.testimonial-left
{
float:left;
margin-left:10%;
}
```

Comment: maybe something like this : quotes: "\201C""\201D""\201C""\201D";

Comment: using this should also work : quotes: "\201C""\201D"; You will get double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set `close-quote` to `blockquote:after`.

Like in normal sentences, single quotes are used within double-quotes!

```
.testimonial blockquote:after {
  content: close-quote;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLwooLvt/1/)

Comment: Oh my god.... I just assumed it was like using an image and not an actual quote. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to close a double quote before opening another double one.
If you don't close it, it displays a single quote, considering the second quote as part of the first one. 
So you need to state a ".testimonial block quote:after" and close it.
Otherwise you need to stile it in illustrator or photoshop and export it as a file, then you can place it wherever you wish. 
Hope it helps.
Cheers